# TreeTable not rendering properly

Tags: angular, treetable

I tried to use the TreeTable component from the ng-treetable package to display a hierarchical structure but it doesnt work properly.  I also used the example you find on github with same results.

When I run this sample in my environment the cells are not aligned with the columns but all content is within the first column. Example:

### Title 1 | Title 2 | Titel 3

a       | b       | c

is what I would expect but I get:

### Title 1 | Title 2 | Titel 3

abc     |         |

Any idea?

Comment: I made some progress - looks like some of the styles  or not properly applied. Ng-treatable need some classes ( ui-teeetable-row, ...) to be defined. Which Stylesheets so I have to include to make this working? Where can I get these Stylesheets from?